# Local variable rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This should be a simple question, I think I'm just having a brain fart from staring at my code too long.

```
jsonlasttengamesopp["games"].each do |opp|
  if opp["gameId"] == x["gameId"]
    opponentkills = opp["stats"]["championsKilled"]
    opponentassists = opp["stats"]["assists"]
    opponentdeaths = opp["stats"]["numDeaths"]
    binding.pry #Binding.pry number 1
    break
  end
    end

binding.pry #Binding.pry number 2
```

The first binding.pry gives me the correct opponentkills, assists, and deaths..

The second binding.pry gives me this error when I call opponentkills:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `opponentkills' for #<Class:0x007f46b0cab428>
```

I should be able to call opponentkills outside of this loop. Shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each blocks creates its own binding, which means that variable created within the block is not accessible outside of this block. However, each block also carries the binding it was created in, hence it has an access to the outside variables. So if you do this instead:

```
opponentkills = nil
jsonlasttengamesopp["games"].each do |opp|
  if opp["gameId"] == x["gameId"]
    opponentkills = opp["stats"]["championsKilled"]
    opponentassists = opp["stats"]["assists"]
    opponentdeaths = opp["stats"]["numDeaths"]
    binding.pry #Binding.pry number 1
    break
  end
end

binding.pry #Binding.pry number 2
```

block will not create a new local variable within its binding, but will use variable from the outside binding.